# Dimension of the space, containing solutions for the matrix equation $g^t X \overline{g} = X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $g_1, g_2 \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be two matrices in [companion form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) and full rank ($c_0 \neq 0$). Consider for $X \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ the matrix equation $g^t X \overline{g} = X$ for $g=g_1,g_2$. One notes, that according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480929/question-regarding-the-entries-of-a-matrix-x-satisfying-gt-x-overlineg-x) any solution $X$ of such an equation is of the form $X=(X_{ij})$ where the entries depend only on $i-j$. I now want to calculate the dimension of the space, which contains the solutions for this equation.

---

The Dimension of the space is equal to number of basis vectors. Lets consider for example the matrix space $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, one usually takes $E_{ij}$ as a basis. In general, an $n \times n$ matrix has two times $n(n−1)/2$ off-diagonal coefficients and $n$ diagonal coefficients. So the dimesnion in said example would be $ 2n(n−1)/2 + n = n^2$.

Regarding my question, i tried finding the dimension in a similar way, but i don´t really know how to get there, since this is a space of those "special" matrices which depend only on $i-j$. My guess is, since $X$ has $n$ columns for $j$ and $n$ rows for $i$ as well as one entry for $i=j$, the dimension is $2n-1$.

**Edit:**

Further examining the linked question, or to be more specific its answer, one sees that the entries of $X$ are in fact given by
$$X_{ij} = X_{(i+1)(j+1)}.$$
So in particular, if you have the entry $X_{11}$ you also get the entire diagonal, similar if you have $X_{(i+1)j}$ or $X_{i(j+1)}$ resp. you get the cooresponding lower resp. upper diagonals. There are $n-1$ upper, lower diagonals each. So we get
$$d + u + l = 1 + (n-1) + (n-1) = 2n-1$$
entries to consider. So the basis would be $\{E_{11}, \{E_{i1}\}_{i=2}^n, \{E_{1j}\}_{j=2}^n\}$ and the dimension is $2n-1$. So does this solve my question?

Comment: Toeplitz matrices (i.e. the elements on the same diagonal are the same) have dimension $2n-1$, but in this case you have a lot of additional constraints. I am not even sure if in the general case there's a non-zero solution

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I added some more thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For almost all $g_1$ and $g_2$ the answer will always be the same, that is, the only $X$ satisfying the hypotheses is the zero matrix. In fact, if you write down the conditions, you will find that the $2n-1$ coefficient of the Toeplitz matrix $X$ are bound by $2n-1$ independent linear conditions.

For example, suppose that $n=2$ and
$$
g = \begin{pmatrix}0&a\\1&b\end{pmatrix}\qquad X = \begin{pmatrix}x&z\\y&x\end{pmatrix}.
$$
From $g^TX\overline g=X$ one can find the conditions
$$
\begin{cases}bx-y+az = 0\\\overline b x + \overline a y -z =0 \\ (|a|^2+|b|^2-1)x + b\overline a y + a\overline bz = 0\end{cases}
$$
that has a nonzero solution in $x,y,z$ only when the determinant of the linear system is zero, but the determinant is
$$|b|^2(|a|^2+1) - (|a|^2-1)^2 + 2\Re(b^2\overline a) $$
that is almost never zero.